# Auth issue when changing a column in Users table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm very new to rails and I'm trying to accomplish the following authentication issue:

User makes a comment or grants "absolution" (similar to comment) and he gets some coins for it. Coins is the virtual currency in my app and is also a column in the users table.

Because of your kind help, I was already capable to update the coins value after writing a comment or grant absolution. However, when I write a comment and log out after that, my login name or password gets changed(?)...I can't login anymore with this account.

This is how my User model looks like:

```
require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :password
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :twitter_url, :homepage_url, :coins

has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :absolutions, :dependent => :destroy

has_many :ratings
has_many :rated_sins, :through => :ratings, :source => :sins

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
homepage_regex = /(^$)|(^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$)/ix

validates :name,  :presence => true,
                  :length => { :maximum => 50 }
validates :email, :presence => true,
                  :format => { :with => email_regex },
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
validates :twitter_url, :format => { :with => homepage_regex }
validates :homepage_url, :format => { :with => homepage_regex }
validates :password, :presence => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length => { :within => 6..40 }

before_save :encrypt_password

def has_password?(submitted_password)
  encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end

def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
  user = find_by_email(email)
  return nil  if user.nil?
  return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
end

class << self
  def authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    (user && user.has_password?(submitted_password)) ? user : nil
  end

  def authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
  end
end

private

  def encrypt_password
    self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
  end

  def make_salt
    secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
  end

  def secure_hash(string)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
  end
end
```

And this is my comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @sin = Sin.find(params[:sin_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.sin_id = @sin.id
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created! Earned 20 coins."
      coins_new = current_user.coins.to_i + 20
      current_user.update_attribute(:coins, coins_new)
      redirect_to sin_path(@sin)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Comment should have 1 - 1000 chars."
      redirect_to sin_path(@sin)
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end



  private 

    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?
    end

end
```

I assume, that it has something to do with the before_save encrypt_password method, but its only a guess. I really appreciate your help and suggestions!

**Edit:**
It gets warmer...It has something to do with the following line in the Comments Controller:

```
current_user.update_attribute(:coins, coins_new)
```

When he updates the :coins column, something seems to go wrong. If you need further info, just drop a comment. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're encrypting the already encrypted password in your "encrypt_password" method.

So, when the user is a `new_record?`, you're taking the password (say it's "cat"), hashing it, and storing it in the database.

So, what gets stored is a cryptographic hash of "cat", which we'll say is "dog"

Then, the next time you're saving the user record, you're taking the hashed password ("dog") in line #2 of your "encrypt_password" method, and **hashing it again**, which we'll say generates "kangaroo".

Next time you log in, your app is hashing the password you enter into the login form "cat", hashing it to "dog", and comparing it to the hashed version in the database, "kangaroo". Oh, but "dog" doesn't match "kangaroo", so the login fails.

**So change:**

```
def encrypt_password
  self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
  self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
end
```

To either:

```
def encrypt_password
  self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
  self.password = decrypt(password) # decrypt it first to the plain text
  self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password) # then re-encrypt the plain text with the salt
end
```

Or:

```
def encrypt_password
  self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
  if (password_has_changed?) # somehow you'll have to figure this out
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, the username isn't changing as you spotted already. I looked at the encrypted_password value. AFTER writing a comment, it changes, but the salt stays the same. Since i'm totally new to rails, what should i do to prevent this?

Comment: Well, you could do a couple of things. You can use one of the authentication gems (I use authlogic, but Devise is becoming very popular as well), and not roll your own authentication solution. If that's not an option, then you need to modify your "encrypt_password" method such that it only re-encrypts the password if the password is actually changing. In other words, when you call that method, if there's no value in the "password" portion of the user hash, then you don't actually need to re-encrypt it.

Comment: Oh, I totally see what's wrong - in your "encrypt_password" method, you're encrypting the password /unless/ it's a new record. If I read that correctly, I think you're taking the encrypted password from the database, and encrypting it again - you're basically hashing the hash of the password. The fix is to either (1) only encrypt it if it's changed (encrypting the new, plain-text password, not the encrypted version from the database), or (2) make sure you decrypt before you re-encrypt. You follow?

Comment: I've completely updated my answer. Your problem is in the encrypt_password method.

Comment: Hm, i'm still a little confused. In comments controller, i'm only setting the coins-value in users table. I'm not sending any password in this controller action. Furthermore, there is no plain password, because I'm only saving the hash. 
I tried to understand it step by step on console. Since a password and the confirmation is needed for saving a user object, the validation is failing for the above increase coin commands (tried it in console). So there "should" be a away, to skip the validation for changing the coins value, so I'm not forced to send a password in comments controller.

Comment: This is basically a code flow problem. I'll draw up do a quick diagram and post it into the answer here in about 20-30 minutes.

Comment: Another approach would be to alter the encrypt method. I added a condition to the second line of it:

self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password) if new_record?

For now, this solved my problem, but this whole work flow is not 100% clear to me right now. So I'm looking forward to your diagram =)

Comment: Ok, I finally got it with your help =) When i was updating the coins in the comments controller, the password was NIL. So NIL got encrypted by the method, you spotted. Changing the code in the encryption method like this solved the problem:

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password) if password.present?
    end

Thanks again for your help. I'll mark your answer as correct =)